# How do I remove the following highlighted items from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

What would be the easiest way to remove the highlighted from the DOM?

If you notice the actual values, they are all 0's. I could maybe select by that but I'm unsure of how to do it.

I also have to remove the labels for each.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('.k-edit-form-container').children().slice(0, 3).remove();
```

or

```
$('.k-edit-form-container').children(':lt(3)').remove();
```

or

```
$('.k-edit-form-container').children().filter(':lt(3)').remove();
```

References

[**.children()**](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[**:lt()**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

[**.slice()**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

[**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[**.remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Good stuff, man. $('.k-edit-form-container').children().slice(0, 8).remove(); did the trick! ps. I need to wait 9 mins to accept ur answer.